# vertical and horizontal scrollbars appear when only the horizontal should

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, resize

I have a situation where when I shrink my `Form` horizontally, both a horizontal AND a vertical `ScrollBar` appear.  I created a new WinForms project to duplicate the behavior, here is the set up I used.

1. Add a `TabControl` to the `Form`, set `Dock` to `Fill`
2. Add a `TableLayoutPanel` to the `TabPage`
3. Set `Dock` to `Fill`, use one row and one column, set `AutoScroll` to `true
4. Set the row and column sizing to `AutoSize`
5. Add a `Label` to the `TableLayoutPanel`, set its text to something long
6. Run the app, shrink the `Form` horizontally
7. Notice both a horizontal and vertical `ScrollBar` appear

This is not a major issue but it feels a little broken and is quite annoying to see after a while. I feel like there's something not resizing properly.  My guess is that the horizontal `Scrollbar` appears, which triggers the `TableLayoutPanel`'s `ScrollBars` instead of shrinking the `TableLayoutPanel` to fit the new vertical space.

I've tried this with using the tab page's `AutoScroll` set to `true` as well, and got the same result.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT:

I tested the same setup with just a `Panel`, `Dock` set to `Fill`, `AutoSize` on and set to `GrowAndShrink`, `AutoScroll` on. The same steps trigger the horizontal, but NOT the vertical `ScrollBar`.

Comment: This is pretty normal.  The horizontal scrollbar appears because you made the window too narrow.  It takes vertical space away by itself, now there is not enough client area space available vertically either.  So the vertical scrollbar appears as well.  Use the SystemInformation class to find out the sizes of the scrollbars so you can add the extra space to avoid this.  Or just leave it up to the user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your guess is correct. As long as the client area does not have enough space to show all the controls, a scroll bar, either vertical or horizontal or even both, will appear.

To avoid this, use `SystemInformation` to get scroll bars information and add extra padding to your controls. For example, to hide horizontal bar, simply do this:

```
var vertScrollWidth = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;

tableLayoutPanel.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, vertScrollWidth, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry, meant to come back to this a while ago.  I was able to use this to solve the general problem in a test WinForms app, but I think I'm going to avoid handling resizing events myself for my app.  Trying to keep it simple!